# Same SKUs, different Title and Description

Tags: magento

I'd like to have articles with same SKU but different title and descriptions in my Magento shop. However Magento is not allowing this as the SKU must be unique (of course that makes sense but not for my case).

Background:
Car parts shop: It is possible that one and the same article fits for different locations on the car. So it would not make sense to add another article with a different SKU/title/sescription for one and the same.

Thus the goal is to have several products with the same SKU but other descriptions and titles.

Any Ideas how to handle that with Magento?

Comment: Why not put it in different categories of use?

Comment: The very definition of SKU forbids this. Why not listing all uses for that article in the description?

Comment: @Dan I think there's no way to make it clear to the customer even if I put it in different categories. In the basket he can only see the product title which needs to be from the one that he placed into the basket.

Comment: @Kai I don't lihe this solution. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do it in Magento what you need.  But I wanted to let you know that for 2.5 years I've been selling tons of products that is same product but for different models of electronic equipment.  It's managed with eBay Turbolister.  It is same SKU or better yet same CUSTOM LABEL for like 2000 different models that take exactly same part like what you do.

For 5 years, I've been selling on eBay volume product in similiar fashion as you.  I use Turbolister.  In Turbolister I use what is called Custom Label to do as you describe to manage 6,500 listings and counting on 2 accounts.

I am using YII PHP Framework with MySQL to build my own price update program which is pulling from 100 different SKU's updated via google docs.  Then calculations done in YII web application I wrote running with XAMPP on my computer.  Now making tables and PHP programming to cross reference those 100 different SKU's to unique item numbers of the 6500 listings on eBay.  For everyone out there that thinks this shouldn't be done....well, it must be done and I've been doing this for 2.5 years+....that is 1 of those 100 SKU's references 2000 unique item id's which reference the 2000 different listing titles for the various models of electronic equipment on eBay via Turbolister.  And several different SKU's each reference several different unique listing titles via the item number on eBay.

So people, what Chris is asking is not wrong or crazy...it's what has to be done and MUST be done!  I think you must write an extension for Magento to do what you want. Or perhaps there already is an extension.

My main purpose of writing here is to let you know that you can and should do what you are asking.

Chris, can you imagine having 2000 different SKU's for 2000 different listing titles on eBay when in reality it's simply 1 and only 1 SKU that needs to be ordered?  No way would I want that.  Rather do it the way you and I are doing with 1 SKU only referencing thousands of listings that take EXACTLY the same type of SKU.  Hey, I'm open to suggestion, but I've been doing this successfully this way for 2.5 years.

Quoted from eBay API, "A SKU is not required to be unique. A seller can specify a particular SKU value on one item or on multiple items." - source: http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellerList.html

"A SKU is not required to be unique, when you track listings by their ItemID (the default tracking method). A seller can specify a particular SKU on one item or on multiple items." - source: http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetItem.html

In a nutshell I'm not tracking my listings by SKU rather by the item ID that eBay automatically assigns to each of my 6,500 active listings.  Rather I'm simply using that SKU to reference all my listings that take that exact type SKU...then I can easily know what needs to be ordered.  Shoot, this is super long winded...anyway, late gotta get back to programming in YII.  Yeah, YII rocks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad idea to overwrite default Magento to allow for such a workaround. Not only will it be very time consuming, but it is also likely to result in a number of functional issues.

My recommendation is to either:

A. Create multiple products based on the same SKU base, i.e. ABC123-1, ABC123-2, etc.

B. Create attributes on the product that will have to be unique. Depending on the category, load the information from the respective attributes. Of course, you'll have to consider what will happen when a product is loaded via search.

Comment: A. There will be a problem with stock keeping in the warehouse when there are more than one SKUs for one and the same product. B. I'd only need to show a part of the attributes for some cars as not all applications are suitable for all cars that products fits on. I don't think that can be handled with Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Think about it another way:

An item with a given SKU has four possible installation locations, all of which apply to four years of four different vehicles. Do you always keep 4x4x4 = 64 quantity on hand to satisfy the end use, and do you have 64 spots in your warehouse where this item? Likely not!

A SKU is a singular, globally-identifying token of a stock item. You will want to create attributes for your items to use for modeling and presenting fitment details.

You may want to use or bootstrap your implementation with an [extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/year-make-model-extension.html).

Comment: Please see B. of my reply to djdy. Is there a possibility to have an attribute - category dependency so that I can chosse which attributes of a product appear in a given category? Not all attributes of a product are suitable for all cars...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had much experience with them myself, but this sounds like a textbook example of [configurable products.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product/)

Answer (score 0):

No configurable product is not what I need. Actually I found the solution.

For my problem I needed to change the Catalog Input Type from drop down to multiple choice. However, Magento devs found appropriate to make this change impossible. You have to choose the type when you create the attribute but can't change it later unless you want to play with your db and code. Very not convenient to say the less... As I don't want to take the risk to mess up with my system I just created a new attribute with Multiple choice option and I'm replacing the attribute for my products now...